# Automatically delete email when a condition is met

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I created several folders and in each of them comes a certain message defined by the rules. Is there a way to set a rule to move messages from a certain folder when a certain message arrives in it? Example: Folder = GBPUSD has several messages and each message contains the word GBPUSD. Then a message arrives in the same folder "Close GBPUSD". When that message arrives, I want to automatically (delete or move all messages from the "GBPUSD" folder anywhere. In fact, to empty the "GBPUSD" folder. I need a way to set the rules if possible...

Since I noticed that the rules don't work on folders, but only on the inbox, it occurred to me to create a few more inboxes (inbox 1 eurusd / inbox 2 gbpusd...) and then apply the above-mentioned rules to them? I think that a common (shared) inbox is just not suitable because I need more of them... and VBA does not enter my head at all. Is there any solution?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As you've already noted, Outlook rules can only be applied to the Inbox (at least for receiving rules, rather than sending rules), not to folders within it. So if you want to automatically delete incoming emails you'd have to do so from the Inbox itself.

Note, there is only one Inbox, and can only be one Inbox. It's the folder that Outlook puts all new emails, so you can add all the Inbox2, Inbox3 folders you want, they will only ever be normal folders as there can be only one default folder to deliver the emails to.

If you want to receive the emails such that you know they're coming in, so don't want to instantly delete them when they arrive, one work around is to create a rule that deletes the emails from the Inbox (so don't move them elsewhere) but don't make the rule active. Then when you want to clear those messages from your Inbox go into your rules and "Run Now" that rule, which will then process all the messages in your Inbox.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think your requirement is feasible in all details.

Even if you manage to trigger a rule when a specific message arrives, there's no action available to delete other mails.

To add to what Keith has shared, instead of using rules to automatically move mails to different folders, you can consider using [Search folder](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-search-folders-to-find-messages-or-other-outlook-items-c1807038-01e4-475e-8869-0ccab0a56dc5) to organize mails including specific keywords. Then create rules to prompt an alert when the specific message arrives using action like"Display a specific message in the New Item Alert window".

[image]

With this setup, you'll be alerted when the specific mail comes in, and then you can modify the criteria of the search folders like below to prevent all the old mails from showing up in the search folder:

[image]